# "HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error :UnsupportedOperationException : Error creating stream from file"- SentinelAPI

Tags: python, sentinel2, sentinelsat

I'm using SentinelAPI (from sentinelsat), to download Satellite imagery from sentinel.
The code i'm using (not fully):

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
products = api.query(fprintile.centroid.wkt,
                                 date=(Idate, Edate),
                                 platformname='Sentinel-2',
                                 processinglevel=levels,
                                 cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 10)
                                 )
```

However, sometimes I get the Error message (example):

```
type error: HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error: UnsupportedOperationException : Error creating stream from file /mnt/s2bl1c/dhus/incoming/x5/x6/x1/S2B_MSIL1C_20210428T182909_N0300_R027_T11SMT_20210428T214807.zip
```

It is important to emphasize that the error is not permanent, that is, if I try to download it at another time it might work successfully.

I would love to hear about a solution to this problem, or alternatively another way to download products from sentinel by API access

Comment: Have you tried the `/apihub` endpoint? It's the official endpoint for programmatic access, and although it's just a mirror, it's supposed to have better availability. Just replace `dhus` with `apihub`, or leave the third arg out in the `SentinelAPI` constructor. If you start getting authentication errors with `apihub` endpoint, well, welcome to the club...